# Determining impassable tiles in A* pathfinder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement an A* pathfinding algorithm in a 2D scene with a `Tilemap`.  In order to do that, I need to calculate which tiles in the grid are passable.  I have a `TilemapCollider2D` attached to the layer on my `Tilemap` that has the walls, but I'm struggling to mesh the collider bounds with each node's bounds (no pun intended).

Each tile in my `Tilemap` is subdivided into 4 nodes for the A* algorithm, in order to give a finer granularity of movement.  I need to be able to take the bounds of each pathfinder node and determine whether it contains a collider region.  My first thought was to use `TilemapCollider2D.OverlapPoint()` to check the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right points of each node to see if any of those points overlap a collider, but then I realized that the problem with that is if a collider sits in the middle of a node without overlapping a corner, that won't work.

My next thought is to create a `Rect` from each node's bounds and then create a polygon from each collider's points (gotten from `Sprite.GetPhysicsShape()`), and then see if the rectangle and polygon overlap, but I'm not sure how to create polygons like that and test for overlapping in Unity.

Here's a basic outline of what I'm trying to do:

```
int xMin = tilemap.cellBounds.x;
int xMax = xMin + tilemap.size.x - 1;
int yMin = tilemap.cellBounds.y;
int yMax = yMin + tilemap.size.y - 1;     

for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++)
{
    for (int y = yMin; y <= yMax; y++)
    {
        // Create four A* nodes for this tile
        Rect node1 = new Rect(x, y, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Rect node2 = new Rect(x + 0.5f, y, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Rect node3 = new Rect(x, y + 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Rect node4 = new Rect(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        var sprite = tilemap.GetSprite(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0));
        if (sprite != null)
        {
            // Get the points that define this sprite's collider shape
            List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();
            sprite.GetPhysicsShape(0, points);

            // This is where I would like to create a polygon from the
            // collider's points and see if that polygon overlaps any
            // of my four A* nodes, but I don't know how to do that
        }
    }
}
```

How do I implement this solution, or is there a better way than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to implement an A* pathfinding algorithm in a 2D scene with a Tilemap. In order to do that, I need to calculate which tiles in the grid are passable. I have a TilemapCollider2D attached to the layer on my Tilemap that has the walls, but I'm struggling to mesh the collider bounds with each node's bounds (no pun intended).

You can mark tiles on your own as impassable with a boolean inside your tile script. Then grab that script on collision (with GetComponent()) and check if it's passable or not.

If it doesn't work with the TilemapCollider2D it will work with a BoxCollider2D.

Comment: Is there a way to get collision data from a TilemapCollider2D into a list of BoxCollider2D or PolygonCollider2D?

Comment: I doubt it. But just let each individual tile have a BoxCollider2D or a PolygonCollider2d. Although I'd attempt with the BoxCollider2D first as Polygon sometimes works a bit funky in my experience. Then you collide with the individual tiles collider.

Comment: My main problem is that I can't find a way to check if `Rect` or other geometry overlaps a collider.  All of the methods seem to only work between two colliders.  Since I'm not actually moving my character (I'm just looping through each tile and seeing if they're passable), I don't have a second collider to test against my tilemap collider(s).

Comment: Make a TileManager that holds a reference to all tiles and their coordinates, for example by having each Tile added to the TileManager when the scene is loaded. Then access that TileManager to get all the tiles and calculate a path based on your players current tile position and the destination.

Comment: That's more-or-less what I'm trying to do.  However, in order to initialize the TileManager and calculate paths, I have to know which pathfinder nodes are impassable.  Since I'm dividing each Tilemap tile into multiple pathfinder nodes, I have to determine whether each pathfinder node contains an obstacle (collider).  That's the point at which I'm stuck.  I can get the coordinates of each collider and get the coordinates of each pathfinder node, but I can't figure out how to calculate whether a collider overlaps a pathfinder node without writing polygon collision from scratch.

Comment: Instead of making each tilepart a Rect, make your own class called TilePart which holds a Rect and a Bool. Then for each coordinate you have the bool "Walkable" or similar. That way you know which are passable and which are impassable.